# How to call SF Console Integration API methods only once per page load

Tags: api, integration, console

I have a console application with it's own separate session/authorization logic.
When I'm logging out from my application it is refreshed, but salesforce page does not, which is ok. It's ok, yet there's one unexpected flaw: in my app I'm calling `sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentPopoutable` during initialization, and it just throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerFunction' of undefined' error when I'm calling it second time (after logout/login in my app).

So, my question is - when salesforce is not refreshed, but console application is reloaded - what is the best way guruantuee any particular call to be don only once, "the very first time".

Currently I'm just try/catching and looking whether error is "good" one but would be very glad to learn how to make it in more elegant way.